# Would citations in blogs, public materials, arXiv and magazines increase citation count for the author?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, scopus

It is known that references from peer reviewed articles and public domain technical reports can increase the citation counts in Scopus and Google scholar. But does this apply to the works cited in the following?

- blogs
- publicly available online materials
- arXiv
- magazines

For instance, if an author *X* has a peer-reviewed article *A* and has *A* cited in each of the above mentioned items, how will his Scopus and Google scholar citation count be affected?

Comment: From my experience: Blogs and magazines no, but arxiv yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopus counts only peer-reviewed articles.

What Google scholar counts is less clearly defined. Intuitively, if something looks like an academic source, then its citations are counted. This means that arXiv is definitely in. I've seen slides for talks hosted on academic webpages being counted, but not in a very consistent manner. I would suspect that most blogs don't count. Mathoverflow does not count.